# RewriteRule not working with the given parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I did some research and spent my last 2 days trying to make my .htaccess work without success, and I can't fully understand how .htaccess really work.

This is the URL I'm trying to rewrite, using GET in my .php files:

**http://localhost/BDsite/tables/table.php?table=Energy**

and I want it to be like this:

**http://localhost/BDsite/tables/Energy**

Well, this is how my .htaccess is written, and its located inside the site folder, which is **/BDsite**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^BDsite/tables/([^/]*)$ /BDsite/tables/table.php?table=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sadly nothing is happening with my URL.

Comment: _nothing is happenning with my url_... Could you be a bit more specific? What happens when you type url `http://localhost/BDsite/tables/energy`?

Comment: Sorry,
when i type http://localhost/BDsite/tables/energy i get ERROR 404, it doesn't found the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to per-server rewrites, it is possible to do rewriting inside  sections or .htaccess files at the expense of some additional complexity. This technique is called per-directory rewrites.

*The main difference with per-server rewrites is that the path prefix of the directory containing the .htaccess file is **stripped** before matching in the RewriteRule.*

A **RewriteBase** should be used to assure the request is properly mapped.

(source: [apache.org - rewrite intro .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html))

So, using your directory structure, and adding the necessary `RewriteBase` you'd get the following that should work:

.htaccess file in root folder (BDsite)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /BDsite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^tables/([^/]*)$ tables/table.php?table=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Project structure:

[image]

So now if you request: `localhost/BDsite/tables/energy`,

you'll get served `localhost/BDsite/tables/table.php?table=energy`
(check this by var_dump-ing $_GET in file table.php)

Comment: Thx, it worked, i tried that before but didin't work, strange, i guess it was because of my browser cache.